# TextWrangler and Line Highlighting

Tags: line, highlight, textwrangler

I don't like the "highlight current line" feature in TextWrangler. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 9):

```
 Preferences -> Text Colors -> Uncheck "Highlight insertion point"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to Alexandre's answer: this has now changed to Settings > Editing > uncheck "Highlight insertion point"